Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction exception
I'm sending the falling document using biztalk  and get the following exception
Document:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <Interface>Request_Doc_Submission_MOTrans_in</Interface>
        <NoOfRecords>1</NoOfRecords>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Message>
            <DocSubmission_InFile>
                <DocSubmission_InFile_Header>
                    <CustomerID>18</CustomerID>
                    <File_name>MOTrans_DocSubmission_In_19062024_1288.xml</File_name>
                    <Ordinal_Number>1288</Ordinal_Number>
                    <File_Creation_Date>19062024 20:08:58</File_Creation_Date>
                    <Total_Records>1</Total_Records>
                </DocSubmission_InFile_Header>
                <DocSubmissionRequests>
                    <DocSubmissionRequestData>
                        <InitialDocumentID>ff4f3c9d-5e2e-ef11-a30e-00505695ca63</InitialDocumentID>
                        <CaseDisplayIdentifier>27310-06-24</CaseDisplayIdentifier>
                        <DocumentOriginName>ff4f3c9d-5e2e-ef11-a30e-00505695ca63.pdf</DocumentOriginName>
                    </DocSubmissionRequestData>
                </DocSubmissionRequests>
            </DocSubmission_InFile>
        </Message>
    </Body>
</Envelope>

Exception:
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/GetResponse.

What can be the problem with the header?

Request_Doc_Submission_MOTrans_in does not look valid.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/submitdirect-biztalk-server-sample

You would probably have to ask the owner of the web service what the expect the SOAPAction to be.
